# JSF 2.0: Is there any advantage in using DataModel<T> over List<T> for CRUD applications

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

One advantage of the datamodel is that you get the row index in a table. But I find this unnecessary, since you can access the current row element using the `var` attribute of h:datatable. And I often need to convert to the datamodel to list, since some component libraries are expecting a list. I am thinking of completely abandoning DataModel. What do you think? Are there any advantages of DataModel.

Thanks,
Theo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another advantage is that you can obtain the currently processed row by [`DataModel#getRowData()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html#getRowData%28%29). This is particularly useful when you want to access the current row during events (conversion/validation, value change listener, action method, etc).

E.g.

```xml
<h:column>
    <h:commandButton value="edit" action="#{bean.edit}" />
</h:column>
```

with

```
public String edit() {
    Item item = dataModel.getRowData();
    // ...
}
```

You can find a basic CRUD example which utilizes this in [this blog](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html). If you wasn't using `DataModel`, you would be forced to use `f:setPropertyActionListener` for this which is only clumsy and won't work for a validator/converter or value change listener. Since EL 2.2, you could also pass the current `var` item as method argument like so:

```xml
<h:commandButton value="edit" action="#{bean.edit(item)}" />
```

with

```
public String edit(Item item) {
    // ...
}
```

While nice, this would only make your webapp incompatible with Java EE 5 based containers.

As to the overhead, the "conversion" from `List<T>` to `DataModel<T>` is particularly cheap. No new items are been copied or created or so, it's just a wrapper class which delegates the methods to the wrapped class and adds another methods to it (see also the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)).

Comment: Can we conclude that the `DataModel` exists for only two functions: for providing row information (not needed with EL 2.2) and for allowing listeners (guess this could be nice sometimes)? A note: using EL 2.2 does not render application incompatible with JEE5 containers (you can manually update their EL libraries), it does render the application incompatible with JEE5 spec, however.